# Run exe file in c# within the program folder

Tags: c#, .net, exe, process.start

I need to start a EXE file from my program directory without giving the full path.

[image]

```
private void programul1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\radum\Desktop\mapa 3 prog\Prog3\Program 1.exe");
}
```

What can i do to give the path only from the ...\Prog3\Program 1.exe ?

Comment: Place the `Program 1.exe` next to the compiled *binary* of your project, not next to the solution file.

Comment: I moved the Program 1.exe next to bin folder , still nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [relative path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Program 1.exe");
```

The code above will work if `Program 1.exe` is *in the same directory as the program running that code* and the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) was not modified using a shortcut for example.

If not then you'll have to find out the path *relative* to your program (the one that should be in `bin/debug/`)

Comment: Can't, it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: As this answer says, make sure the file is actually in the same directory. That's what the comments also say. From your screenshot, it appears your parent program is *not* in the same folder as `Program 1.exe`

Comment: Do you happen to be running your program from Visual Studio? VS would be executing a compiled exe in your debug/release folder, so your working directory would be something like "C:\Users\radum\Desktop\mapa 3 prog\Prog3\Topai Catalin 11.6\Bin\Debug\" instead. (And that's where Program 1.exe would need to be)

Comment: he did say IF.. if not, you can do "..\someotherdir\Program 1.exe" or "somefolder\Program 1.exe" ... this is simple stuff.. but if your exe for program1 can move, then full paths and storing its location is a good idea

Comment: Place the `Program 1.exe` inside the  `Topai Catalin 11.6\Bin\Debug\` dir instead.

Answer (score 1):

Usually solution directory is 3 level up from default output directory so you should use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"..\..\..\Program 1.exe");
```

But you should not do it. You must copy `Program 1.exe` to your output directory and use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Program 1.exe");
```

instead. You can use [post build commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) to perform this operation.
Use this as post build command

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)Program 1.exe" "$(OutDir)Program 1.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Common.AssemblyDirectory returns the folder that contains the running assembly.

So use:
    Path.Combine(Common.AssemblyDirectory, @"Prog3\Program 1.exe");

EDIT: you have edited the question after my answer. As poke said, you put the file in the wrong folder.